# Search in Multilevel RecyclerView not working using EDIT TEXT

Tags: android, search

### I am trying to implement search functionality

I have two recycler view one is horizontal and one is vertical. When I search I get this resulted screen please check I don't know what I am doing wrong please help me.

[Screen Shot-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65XQj.jpg)
[Screen Shot-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzYci.jpg)

```
         My Fragment class
        
         private void filter(String text) {
                ArrayList<DashboardServices> temp = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DashboardServices d : dataModelList) {
                    //or use .equal(text) with you want equal match
                    //use .toLowerCase() for better matches
                    if (d.getName().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase().toString()))
    {
                        temp.add(d);
                    }
                }
                //update recyclerview
                frSevicesAdapter.updateList(temp);
            }
             ------------------------My First Adapter----------------
            @Override
            public FrServicesRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                                           int viewType) {
                binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                        LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                        R.layout.adapter_dashboard_service, parent, false);
                return new ViewHolder(binding);
        
            }
        
            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        
                DashboardServices dataModel = mainTitleArrayListFiltered.get(position);
                ArrayList<DashboardServices> subTitleArrayList = mainTitleArrayListFiltered.get(position).getChildren();
                binding.setDataModel(dataModel);
                LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
                binding.recycleView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                frServicesInsideAdapter = new FrServicesInsideAdapter(subTitleArrayList, context);
                binding.setAdapter(frServicesInsideAdapter);
        
        
            }
        
        
            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return mainTitleArrayListFiltered == null ? 0 : mainTitleArrayListFiltered.size();
            }
        
            public void updateList(ArrayList<DashboardServices> temp) {
                mainTitleArrayListFiltered.clear();
                mainTitleArrayListFiltered = temp;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        
            class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                AdapterDashboardServiceBinding itemRowBinding;
        
                ViewH## Heading ##older(AdapterDashboardServiceBinding itemRowBinding) {
                    super(itemRowBinding.getRoot());
                    this.itemRowBinding = itemRowBinding;
                }
        
            }
```

------------------ My Second inside adapter----------------

```
 public FrServicesInsideAdapter(ArrayList<DashboardServices> dataModelList, Context context) {

        this.dataModelList = dataModelList;
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public FrServicesInsideAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                                 int viewType) {
        AdapterItemViewBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                R.layout.adapter_item_view, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(binding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        DashboardServices dataModel = dataModelList.get(position);
        holder.bind(dataModel);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataModelList == null ? 0 : dataModelList.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        AdapterItemViewBinding itemRowBinding;

        ViewHolder(AdapterItemViewBinding itemRowBinding) {
            super(itemRowBinding.getRoot());
            this.itemRowBinding = itemRowBinding;
        }

        void bind(DashboardServices obj) {
            itemRowBinding.setModel(obj);
            itemRowBinding.executePendingBindings();
        }
    }
```

When I debug the code my inside adapter's `getItemCount` method is not getting called. I don't know why it is not getting called and I am getting a different result I have shared the screen shot please check if anything is required.

Comment: Where is the screenshot? Please edit the code and tag correctly to provide more logic and format it so people in SO can help you!

Comment: Can you please check now.Is it clear to you.